# How to Include Custom Class Files from the Internet into Xcode 4 Project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, class, ios4

I have been [browsing these iOS Cocoa controls](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls) and looking to test out a few in my projects. After downloading them I can find many sub-folders, some with images but mostly header/implementation files. Also the .xcode core project file.

I tried dragging/dropping these into my project window but this doesn't seem to work. I know this is a noob-ish kind of question, but I'm very new to Xcode and just don't understand the interface. For the record I'm running the latest version (Xcode 4.x) under Mac OS X 10.7 Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should drag them into your project. Furthermore you have to import the appropriate header files into e.g. you implementation file (`import "CocoaControl.h"`). Most of the times there's a sample project included with frameworks and custom classes. Check those out to learn how to use them.

Comment: oh okay great. So for the physical class files (such as "CocoaControl.h" in your example) should I move them into my Documents folder with the rest of my project files? ie if I drag-and-drop the files from my desktop, they won't work if I then go and move them afterwards?

Comment: If I were you, I'd just drag them somewhere in you project tree in Xcode and tick `copy files` in the dialog that appears